# deserialize complex json into dictionary like structure

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, structure, json-deserialization

hi ive got a json  file.  that i can modify . but i need to access by its name.
i need to access it like this

```
var result = sitelang.brands["en"] ;      // or
var result = sitelang.["brands"]["en"] ;
```

did i make it understandable . im non native sorry for mistakes. 
than you in advance .   
and good luck!!  with your projects.

**EDİT**   real json file

```
{
"Brands": [
{
  "en": "Brands",
  "tr": "Markalar",
  "de": "Marken",
  "bg": "Производител",
  "el": "μάρκες",
  "uk": "бренди",
  "nl": "Merken",
  }
],
"Products": [
{
  "en": "Products",
  "tr": "Ürünler",
  "de": "Produkte",
  "bg": "Продукти",
  "el": "προϊόντα",
  "uk": "продукти",
  "nl": "producten",
  }
   ],
 "Search_Results": [
  {
  "en": "Arama Sonuçları",
  "tr": "Search Results",
  "de": "Suchergebnisse",
  "bg": "Резултати от търсенето",
  "el": "Αποτελέσματα Αναζήτησης",
  "uk": "Результати пошуку",
  }
 ],
}
```

Comment: I suggest you show your JSON and remove the generated classes as you seem to not want to use them.

Comment: Also can you modify the json if needed or it must be as it is?

Comment: i can modifiy it bu the  usage is what i strongly need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to parse the JSON without declaring classes ahead and then convert it into a dictionary using LINQ:

```
var root = (JObject) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var brands = root["Brands"]
  .AsJEnumerable()
  .First()
  .AsJEnumerable()
  .Cast<JProperty>()
  .ToDictionary(j => j.Name, j => j.Value);
```

To lookup the translation of a specific brand simply use the dictionary:

```
var translatedName = brands["en"];
```

Replace the `"Brands"` string with `"Product"` or `"Search_Results"` to create the other two dictionaries.

From your comment I can understand that you have many translations. In that case you can create a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
var root = (JObject) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var dictionary = root
  .AsJEnumerable()
  .Cast<JProperty>()
  .ToDictionary(
    j => j.Name,
    j => j.Value
      .AsJEnumerable()
      .First()
      .AsJEnumerable()
      .Cast<JProperty>()
      .ToDictionary(k => k.Name, k => k.Value)
  );
```

And get the translated name like this:

```
var translatedName = dictionary["Brands"]["tr"];
```

Comment: looks like just what i need. you make (it / impossible) possible

Comment: what is root[brand] . how to get it ?

Comment: @user3521369: I missed a line of code in my first version of the code but I have edited it some time ago. You should see it if you refresh your browser.

Comment: its great but what if i got 100 item like brands , product, word1 , word2 ...... word100 ? there must be way

Comment: @user3521369: Of course there is. Please see my edit.

Comment: really thank you  ive been tying to split and replace() string output. of root.  im sure this will help tons of people in the future

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify JSON, this is what you want for strong-typed language as C# :

```
"Brands": [
  {
    "language" : "en",
    "translation" : "Brands"
  },
  {
    "language" : "de",
    "translation" : "Marken"
  },
  {
    "language" : "tr",
    "translation" : "Markalar"
  }
//etc
]
```

Then you can access it dynamically based on language property.

Answer (score 1):

**For complex JSON structures, you can use the following: -**

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,dynamic>>(jsonText);

Console.WriteLine(dict["Brands"]); /
Console.WriteLine(dict["Products"]);
```

Comment: can i do it without dynamic  ?

Comment: Yes, add string instead! dynamic is for complex structures where it has more than one level of strings in the JSON. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create this structure of classes for your JSON:
        class SiteLang
        {
            public List Brands { get; set; }
            public List Products { get; set; }
            public List Search_Results { get; set; }
        }

```
    class Language
    {
        public string en { get; set; }
        public string tr { get; set; }
        public string de { get; set; }
        public string bg { get; set; }
        public string el { get; set; }
        public string uk { get; set; }
        public string nl { get; set; } 
    }

    class Brands : Language
    {
    }

    class Products : Language
    {
    }

    class Search_Results : Language
    {
    }
```

And then deserialize your object:

```
var str = @"{
'Brands': [
{
    'en': 'Brands',
    'tr': 'Markalar',
    'de': 'Marken',
    'bg': 'Производител',
    'el': 'μάρκες',
    'uk': 'бренди',
    'nl': 'Merken',
    'fr': 'Marques',
    'ru': 'Бренды',
    'it': 'Marchi',
    'es': 'Marcas',
    'ja': 'ブランド',
    'mk': 'производители',
    'pt': 'Marcas',
    'ar': 'العلامات التجارية'
    }
],
'Products': [
{
    'en': 'Products',
    'tr': 'Ürünler',
    'de': 'Produkte',
    'bg': 'Продукти',
    'el': 'προϊόντα',
    'uk': 'продукти',
    'nl': 'producten',
    'fr': 'Des produits',
    'ru': 'Продукты',
    'it': 'Prodotti',
    'es': 'Productos',
    'ja': '製品',
    'mk': 'производи',
    'pt': 'Produtos',
    'ar': 'المنتجات'
    }
    ],
    'Search_Results': [
    {
    'en': 'Arama Sonuçları',
    'tr': 'Search Results',
    'de': 'Suchergebnisse',
    'bg': 'Резултати от търсенето',
    'el': 'Αποτελέσματα Αναζήτησης',
    'uk': 'Результати пошуку',
    'nl': 'Zoekresultaten',
    'fr': 'Résultats de la recherche',
    'ru': 'результаты поиска',
    'it': 'Risultati di Ricerca',
    'es': 'Resultados de la búsqueda',
    'ja': '検索結果',
    'mk': 'Резултати од пребарувањето',
    'pt': 'Procurar Resultados',
    'ar': 'نتائج البحث'
    }
    ],
}";

var siteLang = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SiteLang>(str);

var s = siteLang.Brands.FirstOrDefault().en;
```